# Python iterate over array of arrays special way

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array of arrays:

`[[[1111, 2222, 3333], [4444, 5555, 6666]], [[7777]], [[8888, 9999]], [[0000]], [[1122, 2233]]]`

I need to get all the possible combinations IN ORDER of the elements of the list.

Expected output for this example:

- `[1111,2222,3333,7777,8888,9999,0000,1122,2233]`
- `[4444, 5555, 6666,7777,8888,9999,0000,1122,2233]`

As you may see in this example the first array of the array is the only one who has two options.

I've tried with something like:

```
for i in array_input:
        for j in i:           
            print ', '.join([str(x) for x in j]),
```

but that is not getting me the expected output because is firstly iterating through the two array[0] options instead of picking one of them and filling the rest and then picking the other one and filling it.

So I want some loop that gets `array[0][0],array[1][0],array[2][0]`... instead of: `array[0][0],array[0][1],array[1][0]`...

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your elements are integers, so `0000` will be shown as `0`:

```
import itertools as it

lst = [[[1111, 2222, 3333], [4444, 5555, 6666]], [[7777]], [[8888, 9999]], [[0000]], [[1122, 2233]]]
out = [list(it.chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in it.product(*lst)]
```

First [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) generates a product of all arguments. Then you need [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use itertools.combinations, lets simplify your example to the list `l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  then you can generate all combinations of length r with:(here i.e. r = 3)

```
import itertools as it

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for e in it.combinations(l, 3):
    print e
=>   ('a', 'b', 'c')
     ('a', 'b', 'd')
     ('a', 'c', 'd')
     ('b', 'c', 'd')
```

if you want to get all combinations just loop your r over the length of l

to overcome the problem with the two arrays you could maybe flatten your list i.e. with something like

```
new_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

full example:

```
import itertools as it

l = [[[1111, 2222, 3333], [4444, 5555, 6666]], [[7777]], [[8888, 9999]], [[0000]], [[1122, 2233]]]
l = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

for n in range(1, len(l)):
    for e in it.combinations(l, n):
        print e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following  ...

```
import operator
reduce(operator.__add__, zip(*array_input)[0])
```

The `zip(*array_input)` basically unzips the array to ...

`[([1111, 2222, 3333], [7777], [8888, 9999], [0], [1122, 2233])]`

`zip(*array_input)[0]` simply remove one level of nesting ...

Finally the `reduce` operator adds the lists to a single list. You could also have done

`reduce(lambda m, n: m+n, zip(*array_input)[0])` but I don't like using lambda functions here ...

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[[1111, 2222, 3333], [4444, 5555, 6666]], [[7777]], [[8888, 9999]], [[0000]], [[1122, 2233]]]
a = []
for i in list1:
 for j in i:
  for k in j:
   a.append(k)
print(a)
```